# Normalizing docx4j using VariablePrepare

Tags: java-8, jaxb, docx4j

I'm trying to normalize a document (attached) using the latest 8.2.0 docx4j core and docx4j-jaxb-referencedImpl 8.2.0
using the commands:

```
WordprocessingMLPackage wmlPackage = Docx4jUtil.getPackage(docMergeRequest.getTemplateFilePath()); // simply a path to the file to be used
MainDocumentPart mainDocumentPart = wmlPackage.getMainDocumentPart();
Docx4jUtil.cleanupBookmarks(mainDocumentPart);
Docx4jUtil.cleanupComments(mainDocumentPart);
VariablePrepare.prepare(wmlPackage);
```

when calling VariablePrepare, I am hit with the following error:

```
9:46:17,691 INFO  [stdout] (default task-109) 2020-06-30 19:46:17,690 INFO  [default task-109] org.docx4j.jaxb.Context: java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
19:46:17,693 INFO  [stdout] (default task-109) 2020-06-30 19:46:17,691 INFO  [default task-109] org.docx4j.jaxb.Context: java.version=1.8.0_222-4-redhat
19:46:17,695 INFO  [stdout] (default task-109) 2020-06-30 19:46:17,693 INFO  [default task-109] org.docx4j.jaxb.Context: java.vm.name=OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
19:46:21,212 INFO  [stdout] (default task-109) 2020-06-30 19:46:21,211 INFO  [default task-109] org.docx4j.jaxb.Context: JAXB Reference Implementation is in use.
19:46:21,394 INFO  [stdout] (default task-109) 2020-06-30 19:46:21,393 INFO  [default task-109] org.docx4j.XmlUtils: setProperty com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
19:46:21,395 INFO  [stdout] (default task-109) 2020-06-30 19:46:21,394 INFO  [default task-109] org.docx4j.XmlUtils: actual: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
19:46:21,396 INFO  [stdout] (default task-109) 2020-06-30 19:46:21,395 INFO  [default task-109] org.docx4j.XmlUtils: setProperty com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
19:46:21,396 INFO  [stdout] (default task-109) 2020-06-30 19:46:21,396 INFO  [default task-109] org.docx4j.XmlUtils: actual: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
19:46:21,426 INFO  [stdout] (default task-109) 2020-06-30 19:46:21,424 INFO  [default task-109] org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager: Detected WordProcessingML package
19:46:21,431 INFO  [stdout] (default task-109) 2020-06-30 19:46:21,431 INFO  [default task-109] org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager: Detected WordProcessingML package
19:46:21,432 INFO  [stdout] (default task-109) 2020-06-30 19:46:21,431 INFO  [default task-109] org.docx4j.openpackaging.io3.Load3: Instantiated package of type org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage
19:46:21,437 INFO  [stdout] (default task-109) 2020-06-30 19:46:21,436 INFO  [default task-109] org.docx4j.utils.XPathFactoryUtil: xpath implementation: __redirected.__XPathFactory
19:46:21,452 INFO  [stdout] (default task-109) 2020-06-30 19:46:21,451 INFO  [default task-109] org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager: Using DocPropsCustomPart ...
19:46:21,453 INFO  [stdout] (default task-109) 2020-06-30 19:46:21,452 INFO  [default task-109] org.docx4j.openpackaging.io3.Load3: package read;  elapsed time: 3784 ms
19:46:21,703 INFO  [stdout] (default task-109) 2020-06-30 19:46:21,702 INFO  [default task-109] org.docx4j.jaxb.NamespacePrefixMapperUtils: Using ri.NamespacePrefixMapper, which is suitable for the JAXB RI
19:46:21,789 INFO  [stdout] (default task-109) 2020-06-30 19:46:21,788 INFO  [default task-109] org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.DocPropsExtendedPart: unmarshalling org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.DocPropsExtendedPart
19:46:21,798 INFO  [stdout] (default task-109) 2020-06-30 19:46:21,798 INFO  [default task-109] org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.DocPropsCorePart: unmarshalling org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.DocPropsCorePart
19:46:22,025 INFO  [stdout] (default task-109) 2020-06-30 19:46:22,024 INFO  [default task-109] org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.DocPropsCustomPart: unmarshalling org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.DocPropsCustomPart
19:46:22,027 INFO  [stdout] (default task-109) 2020-06-30 19:46:22,027 INFO  [default task-109] org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.DocPropsCustomPart:
19:46:22,028 INFO  [stdout] (default task-109)
19:46:22,028 INFO  [stdout] (default task-109) org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.DocPropsCustomPart unmarshalled
19:46:22,028 INFO  [stdout] (default task-109)
19:46:22,028 INFO  [stdout] (default task-109)
19:46:22,140 INFO  [stdout] (default task-109) 2020-06-30 19:46:22,140 INFO  [default task-109] org.docx4j.XmlUtils: Using org.docx4j.org.apache.xalan.transformer.TransformerImpl
19:46:22,362 INFO  [stdout] (default task-109) 2020-06-30 19:46:22,361 INFO  [default task-109] org.docx4j.openpackaging.contenttype.ContentTypeManager: Detected WordProcessingML package
19:46:22,362 INFO  [stdout] (default task-109) 2020-06-30 19:46:22,362 INFO  [default task-109] org.docx4j.convert.in.FlatOpcXmlImporter: Creating org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage
19:46:22,364 INFO  [stdout] (default task-109) 2020-06-30 19:46:22,364 ERROR [default task-109] org.docx4j.convert.in.FlatOpcXmlImporter: prefix dcterms is not bound to a namespace
19:46:22,366 INFO  [stdout] (default task-109) 2020-06-30 19:46:22,365 ERROR [default task-109] org.docx4j.convert.in.FlatOpcXmlImporter: <cp:coreProperties xmlns:cp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/metadata/core-properties"><dcterms:created xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2020-03-03T08:48:00Z</dcterms:created><dc:creator xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">Trainee</dc:creator><dc:description xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"/><cp:keywords/><cp:lastModifiedBy>Julie Ann Tesorero</cp:lastModifiedBy><dcterms:modified xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2020-06-18T09:55:00Z</dcterms:modified><cp:revision>36</cp:revision><dc:subject xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"/><dc:title xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"/></cp:coreProperties>
19:46:22,367 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109) java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: prefix dcterms is not bound to a namespace
19:46:22,367 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at com.sun.xml.bind.DatatypeConverterImpl._parseQName(DatatypeConverterImpl.java:370)
19:46:22,367 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.XsiTypeLoader.parseXsiType(XsiTypeLoader.java:96)
19:46:22,367 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.XsiTypeLoader.startElement(XsiTypeLoader.java:74)
19:46:22,367 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext._startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:577)
19:46:22,368 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.startElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:556)
19:46:22,368 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.InterningXmlVisitor.startElement(InterningXmlVisitor.java:75)
19:46:22,368 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.startElement(SAXConnector.java:168)
19:46:22,368 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:244)
19:46:22,368 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:281)
19:46:22,368 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.visit(DOMScanner.java:250)
19:46:22,368 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at com.sun.xml.bind.unmarshaller.DOMScanner.scan(DOMScanner.java:127)
19:46:22,368 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:369)
19:46:22,368 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:352)
19:46:22,368 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.JaxbXmlPart.unmarshal(JaxbXmlPart.java:1111)
19:46:22,369 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at org.docx4j.convert.in.FlatOpcXmlImporter.getRawPart(FlatOpcXmlImporter.java:477)
19:46:22,369 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at org.docx4j.convert.in.FlatOpcXmlImporter.getRawPart(FlatOpcXmlImporter.java:427)
19:46:22,369 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at org.docx4j.convert.in.FlatOpcXmlImporter.getPart(FlatOpcXmlImporter.java:366)
19:46:22,369 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at org.docx4j.convert.in.FlatOpcXmlImporter.addPartsFromRelationships(FlatOpcXmlImporter.java:296)
19:46:22,369 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at org.docx4j.convert.in.FlatOpcXmlImporter.get(FlatOpcXmlImporter.java:222)
19:46:22,369 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.transform(WordprocessingMLPackage.java:256)
19:46:22,369 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage.filter(WordprocessingMLPackage.java:295)
19:46:22,369 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at org.docx4j.model.datastorage.migration.VariablePrepare.prepare(VariablePrepare.java:111)
19:46:22,369 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at org.docx4j.model.datastorage.migration.VariablePrepare.prepare(VariablePrepare.java:78)
19:46:22,370 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at sg.gov.ura.dax2.docmerge.core.impls.docx4j.Docx4jGenerator.processDocMergeTemplate(Docx4jGenerator.java:88)
19:46:22,370 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
19:46:22,370 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
19:46:22,370 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
19:46:22,370 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
19:46:22,370 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:338)
19:46:22,370 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:197)
19:46:22,370 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
19:46:22,370 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:294)
19:46:22,371 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:98)
19:46:22,371 ERROR [stderr] (default task-109)  at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:185)
....
```

The code is running on jboss 7.1, I was previously using 6.1.2 but were encountering issues when noramlizing causes the file to be corrupt hence the idea from an old post contained updating the dependency to a newer one.

Note that this issue I posted in docx4j forums as well but I think will gather more response from here.
[Docx4j Forums](https://www.docx4java.org/forums/docx-java-f6/normalizing-docx-using-variableprepare-t2926.html)

**Update #1** - In line with what Jason has requested me to try, log results as follows:

```
09:34:14,626 INFO  [stdout] (default task-110) 2020-07-03 09:34:14,625 INFO  [default task-110] org.docx4j.XmlUtils: setProperty com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
09:34:14,627 INFO  [stdout] (default task-110) 2020-07-03 09:34:14,626 INFO  [default task-110] org.docx4j.XmlUtils: actual: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserFactoryImpl
09:34:14,627 INFO  [stdout] (default task-110) 2020-07-03 09:34:14,627 INFO  [default task-110] org.docx4j.XmlUtils: setProperty com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
09:34:14,628 INFO  [stdout] (default task-110) 2020-07-03 09:34:14,628 INFO  [default task-110] org.docx4j.XmlUtils: actual: com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderFactoryImpl
09:34:14,660 INFO  [stdout] (default task-110) dom.getClass().getName(): com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl
09:34:14,663 INFO  [stdout] (default task-110) 2020-07-03 09:34:14,662 INFO  [default task-110] org.docx4j.jaxb.Context: java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
09:34:14,664 INFO  [stdout] (default task-110) 2020-07-03 09:34:14,663 INFO  [default task-110] org.docx4j.jaxb.Context: java.version=1.8.0_222-4-redhat
09:34:14,665 INFO  [stdout] (default task-110) 2020-07-03 09:34:14,664 INFO  [default task-110] org.docx4j.jaxb.Context: java.vm.name=OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
09:34:18,589 INFO  [stdout] (default task-110) 2020-07-03 09:34:18,588 INFO  [default task-110] org.docx4j.jaxb.Context: JAXB Reference Implementation is in use.
09:34:18,767 INFO  [stdout] (default task-110) o.getClass().getName(): org.docx4j.docProps.core.CoreProperties
```

Answer (score 0):

Your logs include:

```
<cp:coreProperties
    xmlns:cp="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/metadata/core-properties">
    <dcterms:created
        xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2020-03-03T08:48:00Z</dcterms:created>
    <dc:creator xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">Trainee</dc:creator>
    <dc:description
        xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" />
    <cp:keywords />
    <dcterms:modified
        xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2020-06-18T09:55:00Z</dcterms:modified>
    <cp:revision>36</cp:revision>
    <dc:subject xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" />
    <dc:title xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" />
</cp:coreProperties>
```

You can see the xmlns:dcterms="http://purl.org/dc/terms/" declaration.

I suspect it isn't that which is the problem, but rather, the xsi:type

Trying to reproduce this, what happens if you save that as foo.xml then run:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;

import org.docx4j.XmlUtils;
import org.docx4j.jaxb.Context;
import org.docx4j.jaxb.JaxbValidationEventHandler;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;

public class XsiTest {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JAXBException, SAXException, IOException {
        
        DocumentBuilder db = XmlUtils.getNewDocumentBuilder();
        Document dom = db.parse(new File( "foo.xml" ));
        System.out.println(dom.getClass().getName());
        
        Unmarshaller u = Context.jcDocPropsCore.createUnmarshaller();
        JaxbValidationEventHandler eventHandler = new JaxbValidationEventHandler();
        eventHandler.setContinue(false);
        u.setEventHandler(eventHandler);
        
        Object o = XmlUtils.unwrap(u.unmarshal( dom.getDocumentElement() ) );
        
        System.out.println(o.getClass().getName());

    }
    
}
```

Comment: I got com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl for the dom and org.docx4j.docProps.core.CoreProperties for the second one.

Comment: So that works, presumably in your dev environment.  Can you run it in JBoss 7.1, with the same jars on your classpath as you have for your real app?

Comment: Yes, those are actually the ones I got from doing what you just gave. I'm going to update the main post for your reference.